# What does this CSS line segment mean? . . " scroll 100% 0 transparent "

Tags: html, css, twitter

I was perusing an excellent tutorial on using Twitter feeds (from Adam Green at http://140dev.com  )

I'm going through the code pretty carefully and there was a line in the CSS file that I just do not understand.  Not sure where to go to look it up, either.

```
.tweet_triangle {
    background:url(../images/twitter_triangle.gif) no-repeat scroll 100% 0 transparent;
    . . . 
}
```

I know how this div/image is working, but I just don't understand the "scroll 100% 0 transparent" portion of the background call out.  Not sure what it means, not sure where to go to look for it.  And yeah, I feel stupid asking this question here. I gotta believe somebody has been here before. "^)

Comment: From Estelle Weyl [standardista](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties) `Before CSS3, the values could be in any order, but were generally in the color, image, attachment, position and repeat order.`. No need for scroll except if stated previously in another declaration.

Comment: FYI 0 == left|top; 50%==center; 100%==right|bottom (so much natural). To answer your comment below "The percentage thing is not intuitive", what is even less intuitive is values different than 0, 50% and 100% like 33%: the point at 33% in a direction of the image will be displayed at 33% of the element in the same direction (same with 82.5% at 82.5%, etc). It makes perfect sense when you test with 50% ("oh but it's just centered") but you've to take a pencil and paper or test with a checkerboard image to understand the trick for other values. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is

background is a short-cut in CSS that can be used to set multiple background properties at once.

```
background-image: url("../images/twitter_triangle.gif");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 100% 0;//The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical. 
background-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Sridhar, with your help, that now makes sense.  The percentage thing is not intuitive, but now I can figure out where to look to understand what is going on.  Many thanks for your prompt reply.